# Function to find similar words in a given string in C

Tags: c

Me and my course-mates can't seem to solve this question. (It's homework)
We have been trying for 2 weeks but we couldnt figure it out.

As in the title, we need to write a function that will find Similar Words in a given string.
Similar Words: 2 words that contain the same letters (doesn't matter if uppercase or lowercase and how many times the same letter appears).  Example: Cheap - peach.  Nanny - any.

The problem is that we are allowed to use the stdio.h library only, can't use the memory allocation functions and can't use dynamic arrays.

I hope I have been clear enough about the question. 
Please help us solve this puzzle.

Comment: We havent studied bit masking yet, so we can't use it.

Comment: Hint: sort the letters of each word.

Comment: You have to show us something that you tried. Ask us when you have something started but got stuck somewhere.

Comment: @alk I'm not sure how that helps us.

Comment: @JamesGiacomoKintaroSonnino go on paper take some words sort the letters and you'll see. Pay attention how that looks for similar words and how that looks for non-similar words.

Comment: @bolov Well, we thought about iterating through the sentence and storing in an array each word.  The problem is that we don't know what the size of the array should be, so we don't even know where to start...

Comment: @JamesGiacomoKintaroSonnino Never get stuck on things like this `we don't know what the size of the array should be, so we don't even know where to start..` Always move forward. If you can't solve a particular problem, after a certain amount of time you have to skip over it (asume something, ignore it, whatever it takes to move forward). In your case you can assume a max length for sencence and words and allocate array for that. And you move on to solve your actual problem. In your homework you write that assumption in a README ... (max characters, continuing...)

Comment: ... along with a short explanation of why you made that assumption (problem weakly specified, not understanding the problem, not understanding the algorithm etc)

Comment: @bolov Thank you for your precious advice.  We really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like: (needs the proper case conversion, left as an exercise to the reader)
And you need a similar iterator to traverse the words in the sentence.

```
bool wordsAreSimilar(char* string1, char* string2)
{
    bool letterFound = false;
    char *s1_iterator = string1;
    char *s2_iterator = string2;

    for ( ; *s1_iterator != '\0' ; s1_iterator++ )
    {
        for ( s2_iterator = string2, letterFound = false ;
              /* word terminator needs improvement */
              (*s2_iterator != '\0' && *s2_iterator != ' ') 
               && !letterFound ;
              s2_iterator++ )
        {
           letterFound = (*s1_iterator == *s2_iterator);
        }
        if (!letterFound) return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: This function receives 2 words as arguments.  The problem is that I dont have those two words, our function gets a full sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean array to track down which letter is appeared in each of the word (since yu are allowed to use only `stdio.h`, declare it as `int` array) and initialize all elements to `0` (aasuming the string doesn't contain more than 20 words):

```
int words[20][26] = {0} // First dimension is for words and second is for 26 letters.
```

For each word, replace `0` with `1` if a letter is found first time in a word. After that just compare the array elements to figure out which word is made of same letters.

Comment: One line, one bug already on strings that contain words of length 21.

Comment: @Pieter21; Where is written in this answer that words are of length `21`?

Comment: I personally liked the idea.

Comment: @JamesGiacomoKintaroSonnino; Then just implement it. I can post the code but its your homework so you have to learn.

Comment: Where is it stated that we may assume that words are at most 20 letters? And this is just faking dynamic memory allocation.

I am convinded that the teacher want to see the pointer handling stuff.

Comment: @Pieter21; I said, WHERE DID IN THIS ANSWER STATED THAT words are at most 20 letters?